# Active Directory, what forest model should I use

Tags: active-directory

I need my users to be in different security groups and the ability to delegate control. What forest model can I/should I use? And why?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't much detail in the question that would require any special Active Directory Architecture.  If all you want is groups and delegation you can simply drop a domain controller in and be alright.

That is a single forest topology with a single domain.  It is simple, effective, and takes little to no expertise initially.

Typically if you are asking the question which should I use, you are at a point where you should start out with a simple topology until you have the requisite understanding and experience.